# Rspec should_receive doesn't work for module that extends self

Tags: ruby, rspec

Tested module

```
module Notifications
  extend self

  def notify(push_id, platform, message, event, args)
    puts "hello"
    ...     
  end
end


Notifications.should_receive(:notify)
```

Rspec says that notify wasn't called, however "hello" is printed to log.

Comment: You didn't include the code that is supposed to have caused this invocation. I imagine that if this module was included in a class, `#notify` was invoked on an instance of the class, then "hello" should be printed, but Notifications would never have been the receiver of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me:

```
module Notifications
  extend self

  def notify(push_id, platform, message, event, args)
    puts "hello"
  end
end


describe 'RSpec stubbing' do
  it "works when I don't stub" do
    Notifications.should_not_receive(:notify)
  end

  specify 'works when I do stub' do
    Notifications.should_receive(:notify)
    Notifications.notify(1,2,3,4,5)
  end
end
```

Your code is obviously wrong, though, because when you do `#should_receive` it doesn't invoke the original method. If you can see "hello" being printed out, then it is not getting caught by RSpec. Probably you're confused about whether you're stubbing an instance or the module itself.

Comment: This is only code sample. Inside spec i invoke code that should invoke Notifications.notify inside it.

Comment: I have declared should receive before calling method with invokation and it starts work.